# Update panel not updating after text change first pass through

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, updatepanel

This question has been asked several times but I haven't found any related to my situation, so if this is redundant then I apologize!

I am trying to set up a text box so that when you enter in a dealer number, the name and other information is populated.  I have autopostback to true and I do change focus to another control.  Also, everything in this panel is wrapped in an update panel (saw on another post someone suggested it may be due to different update panels).

When I go back to the text box and enter in the number again and then click off to another control it works as expected.  Anyone have any tips of why this has to be entered in twice?

Text Box Control:

```
 <div class="formControl">
    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="DealerNumberRadTextBox" AutoPostBack="true"Width="100%"OnTextChanged="DealerNumberRadComboBoxTextChanged"></telerik:RadTextBox>
 </div>
```

Update Panel line:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a TextChanged event to the textbox?  This should fire after you enter a text into the text box and change focas.

Comment: Yes, I have a text changed event on the text control sorry I forgot to add a sample of that!

Comment: Do you have a trigger calling it for the update panel to trigger on?

Comment: I do not as it is not set to conditional in the update panel.

Comment: welp thanks to all who tried to offer help.  I have no idea why this is happening but put a break point on the textchanged event method and now it works on the first pass through.... changed nothing from earlier. *shrugs* thanks guys.